# Visual Studio Print Preview Control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, printing

I am attempting to create a print preview of a document when the user selects the document from a listview. I know I need to create a print document and pass it to the printpreviewcontrol, but I don't know how to "assign" a file to the printdocument (I know my example below simply gives it a name). Is this possible? All examples I have found in forums and MSDN deal with basic textfiles. For example, how to printpreview office docs, pdf, etc.?

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument


Public Class Form1


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    PrintDocument1.DocumentName = "C:\Documents and Settings\Practice.xlsx"

    PrintPreviewControl1.Document = PrintDocument1


End Sub


End Class
```

Any help would be appreciated. I feel like I am missing something simple. Thanks!

Comment: Why did you add `c#` tag? It is irrelevant. Deleted..

Comment: Perhaps somebody knows the solution in C# since it is fundamentally the same language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PrintDocument object, despite its name, is not a document "reader." The only thing it does is manage the printing process for whatever thing it is that you want to print. The "thing" you want to print can be anything, and the way you print it is by making GDI+ graphics calls, like "draw a line from here to here" and "put this text here at this size." In other words, you create the printed document by calling methods on a `System.Drawing.Graphics.Graphics` object.

So, in order to load a PDF, Word Doc, or any other "document" format, you will need to find a library that allows you to render the document using GDI+. A quick Google search turned up [PDFRasterizer.Net](http://www.tallcomponents.com/pdfrasterizer3.aspx) for PDF files, for example.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this; I was beginning to stumble upon the graphic object caveat. Thank you for helping.